# Not able to check whether user opens app from lock screen OR from home button press on ios 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7, ios8

I am developing an application where i want  to know whether user opens the app from Home button press OR by auto lock/By pressing the Lock button of device. I was google for the things, but for the solutions are not compatible with ios 8.

I have gone through below link but not working in my case:
[Detecting when app is becoming active from lockscreen vs other on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452696/detecting-when-app-is-becoming-active-from-lockscreen-vs-other-on-ios7).

please help me. Getting stuck on this point from couple of days.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Not possible unless you Jailbreak.

Comment: i figure it out by maintaining a Bool Variable to check if user opens app from lockscreen or by pressing home button. Anyways thanks for your reply.