# How to find out if "resume" event is fired from click on an icon and not from waking up the tablet in appcelerator titanium?

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I have an "resume" event listener and i want to be able to distinct from firing the event because the user clicked the application icon or the user locked the tablet and then unlocked.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @LuisMiguel It is a big and complex application and my event listener is not implemented yet.

Comment: This sort of question is too broad/generic, so it will probably be closed. Follow the guidelines for appropriate questions to post in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no way to do this in Obj-C/Swift, so the same goes for Titanium then. Although you might be able to do a hack similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19637857/4626813

Answer (score 0):

There is one more event listener named as **"resumed"** `Ti.App.addEventListener("resumed",function(){});`

This will listen when device is unlocked.